# How to run raw MongoDB operations using the db.command() and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've set of new Mongodb scripts for every release and i'm trying to create `NodeJS` utility to run the scripts by reading from `.txt` files which are there in folder.

Ex: In 1.txt file i've this command `db.getCollection("users").createIndex({ name: 1 });` and i want to run using NodeJS

I've `NodeJs` program like below

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const uri = "mongodb:uri";

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();

    const db = client.db("employee");
    // I want to run above script like here. How can i do it?
    const result = await db.command({
      dbStats: 1,
    });
    console.log(result);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

Comment: For further information look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69676854/how-to-execute-a-string-as-a-mongo-query-in-node-js-here-are-my-sketches-db-ev/77108702#77108702)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your `.txt` file could be a `.js` file. You would then feed it to your mongodb instance like so `mongo < yourFile.js`

But if for some reason this can not be done.

### Eval

Disclaimer: Please be advised of the [security concerned of using eval](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94017/what-are-the-security-issues-with-eval-in-javascript)

I feel what you are looking for is [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Your code could simply look like:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const uri = "mongodb:uri";


MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db){

    const dbo = db.db("test");
    // Here you get your lines from your .txt file
    let line_to_execute = 'dbo.collection("customers").findOne({}, (err, res)=>{console.log(res)});';

    // Launch the execution of line_to_execute
    eval(line_to_execute);

})
```

Comment: Thank you, but where are you executing line_to_execute ?  its not working

Comment: I added some comments to make it more clear.
The `eval` call should be executing the line_to_execute

Comment: Eval doesn't execute the query. It's not expression correct

Comment: What do you mean by `it is not expression correct` ? It should be able to run any valid js expression. Even those doing queries to the database.

Comment: No . Please try a sample program to run above script and let me know.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi I will do, what error do you have ?

Comment: So, I have been playing around a bit ... It does work. The issue you are experiencing is you are using raw queries that are design to run in `mongosh` not in the nodejs middleware. So if you do not want to modify slightly the input. I suggest to look at the first lines of my answer. Feel the file directly in the mongo instance.

Comment: Can you paste the complete working code here

Comment: I have editedy answer, so the snippet is what I managed to get working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, we can read from .Json files and pass the cmd like below.

```
     let userNameIndex = {
        createIndexes: "users",
        indexes: [
            {
                key: { "name": 1 },
                name: "nameIndex"
            }
        ],
        comment: "Prasad test"
    };
    eval(userNameIndex);
    const result = await db.command(userNameIndex);
    console.log(result);
```