# How to execute a string as a mongo query in Node JS. Here are my sketches. db.eval error is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I saw somewhere to do something you need to do something with db.eval, but node throw error that eval is not a function. I wanna execute string as mongo query. It DYNAMIC

```
const mongoClient = require("mongodb");
const url = "someurl";
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url)

async function run() {
    try {
        await mongoClient.connect();
        const db = mongoClient.db("somedb");
        
       
        var query = "db.getCollection('somecollection').find().limit(1)";
        db.eval('function(){ return ' + query + '.toArray(); }', function (err, res) {
            console.log(res);
        });

    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } finally {
        await mongoClient.close();
    }
}
run();
```

Comment: Are you sure its ```const mongoose = require("mongodb");``` and not ```const mongoose = require("mongoose")``` ? if you are using mongoose you dont need to connect using mongoClient. Also why do you want to convert string to query, why not hardcode it, lookup https://mongoosejs.com/docs/ documentation for that.

Comment: it's mongodb. i just forgot. but error not it. I didnt fount answer in docs. I wanna execute string as mongo query. I dont know what is in string.

Answer (score 0):

My friend,

I found the following paragraph on MongoDB Atlas documentation

**Unsupported Commands**
The following table lists the most common commands and shell methods that database user privileges do not support. To ensure cluster stability and performance, Atlas subsumes or restricts the functionality that these commands provide.

"...eval..."

Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/unsupported-commands/

So you may have a paid version to your code run on MongoDB Atlas.

On CosmosDB (Azure version of mongo), you can use it (it's not free).

So, if you want to execute it for free, I would sugest you to maybe install a docker version of mongodb?

Also, Eval was deprecated on version 3.

"...There is no alternative from a driver perspective other than coding the functionality from the driver. However, you still can use the shell directly, which is a javascript runtime..."

Best of lucks!